# How do you form the opposite statement of an 'any' condition?

Tags: python, list, modulus, any

I have the following code which works

`[i for i in range(1, 16) if any(i % j == 0 for j in [3,5])]`

This has an output of
[3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15], the numbers that can be divided by either 3 or 5.

However, when I try

`[i for i in range(1, 16) if any(i % j != 0 for j in [3,5])]`

I get
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]

What I'm looking for instead is
[1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 11, 13, 14]

Many thanks!

Comment: That is because you are using the `any` you should use `not any( == )` instead when you are inverting it.

Comment: The opposite of "any" is "not all".

Answer (score 3):

You need to negate the condition *and* switch to `all`:

```
>>> [i for i in range(1, 16) if all(i % j != 0 for j in [3,5])]
[1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 11, 13, 14]
```

or leave the condition as-is and negate the result of `any`:

```
>>> [i for i in range(1, 16) if not any(i % j == 0 for j in [3,5])]
[1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 11, 13, 14]
```

---

Both can be derived from [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws), one of which states that

```
not (A or B) == not A and not B
```

(which generalizes to `not (A or B or ... ) == not A and not B and ...`).

`any(Ai for i in ...)` is equivalent to `A0 or A1 or A2 or ... or An`, and `all(Ai for i in ...)` is equivalent to `A0 and A1 and A2 or ... or An`.

Comment: I understand the second solution. In the first one I'm guessing conditions for all j need to be True.

Comment: Correct. De Morgan's other law is that `not (A and B) == not A or not B`.  `not (i % j != 0)` is the same as `i % j == 0` (and conversely, `not (i % j == 0)` is `i % j != 0`).

Answer (score 2):

`[i for i in range(1, 16) if not any(i % j == 0 for j in [3,5])]`

Comment: Affirmative. So you reject the condition you don't want rather than changing the condition. Many thanks!